# How to create xpi file with 7Zip?

Tags: firefox-addon, xpi

I would like to pack my firefox extension as xpi file. I tried by adding it to archive and name it as filename.xpi

But when i try to install it on firefox am getting "package corrupted" message. Is there any way i can create a valid xpi file ?

I have installed cygwin and tried to execute zip command to create xpi file. But got zip is not a command error.

Can somebody guide me to get it done ?

Comment: Did you managed to make it work?

Comment: Also note, that if you're using the Addon-SDK, you must use the cfx tool to create the xpi, as that involves other build processes.

Comment: Note that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Signing_a_XPI recommends against 7-zip when signing XPIs, as signed XPIs must have `META-INF/zigbert.rsa` as their first entry, rather than sorted alphabetically as is done by 7-zip..

Comment: The META-INF/zigbert.rsa is filed as 7-Zip Bug 496; see https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/bugs/496/.

Comment: updated method of self-distributing ff extensions https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/publish/submitting-an-add-on/#self-distribution

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you are on windows (to install cygwin it looks like you do), you can use the windows built in tool:

1. Select the contents of the extension (remember, don't select the outside folder).
2. Right Click
3. Send to
4. Compressed (zipped) folder

Then just replace the .zip for .xpi in the filename

Looks like your problem is on completing the point 1. correctly. Select only the contents of the extension. Not the folder that contains it.

So basically your zip file should have following structure:

```
my_extension.zip
  |- install.rdf
  |- chrome.manifest
  |- <chrome>
```

and NOT this structure:

```
my_extension.zip
  |- <my_extension>
       |- install.rdf
       |- chrome.manifest
       |- <chrome>
```

Comment: thanks for replying sir... i have tried the same way but got "Package Invalid" error while installing it on firefox... so i took shell access in my host and tried it with zip command in my linux server and it creates xpi which works fine in firefox...

Comment: I got the "corrupted" message in the past, but that was because i didn't have the contents directly inside the zip file. Otherwise i'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: @user2301765. Could it be that you are using the addon-sdk?

Comment: To do this on OS X you can select all the files in the Finder and click "Compress X items" which will produce an "Archive.zip"

Comment: This should be at the top of Mozilla's submission page. I couldnt find anything on their site explaining how to do this and it is not intuitive in the least.

Comment: If you're using Windows 10, you can also select all extension folders and files, then click the Zip icon found under the Share tab of the Windows Explorer ribbon. This is faster than using the context menu if you're repeatedly compressing the files for extension testing.

Also, it's not necessary to change the extension from .zip to .xpi if you're dragging the file onto the add-ons window.

Comment: It's worth noting, however, that Windows 10's zip tool has the limitation that you can't zip files located in a directory with atypical characters like em dash (—) or right single quotation mark (’) (i.e., an apostrophe). So, if your extension has such characters in its name, you can't use such name as the extension folder name if you want to be able to easily zip the files with the OS tool.

Comment: I don't understand why this post is checked as "solved"?! This method doesn't work for Firefox 60.*.* and newest

Answer (score 9):

I experienced the same problems today and found the error to be that the add-on was obviously not signed by Mozilla, causing Firefox to refuse the installation. Up until recently, it was possible to by-pass this security check by setting `xpinstall.signatures.required` to false in `about:config`. However, as of Firefox 46, signing is mandatory and no by-pass is provided any longer, see https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2016/01/22/add-on-signing-update/ This means that one has to either downgrade to a previous version or use a non release channel version to test one's addons :(

Answer (score 3):

Also, here's how I pack an extension for Firefox with **command line** *7z*:

```
cd /the/extension/folder/
7z a ../<extension_name>.xpi * -r
```

(where 'a' stands for "add/create" and "-r" for recursive)

Or to update the extension with the file(s) we just edited:

```
cd /the/extension/folder/
7z u ../<extension_name>.xpi * -r
```

("u" for update the archive's content)

Comment: Nice trick. I can create a shortcut in the extension folder to automate the compression process: `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k cd "C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Extensions\<extension.folder>\" & "%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe"  a ".\<extension.folder>.xpi" -r chrome defaults chrome.manifest install.rdf`. Too bad 7-Zip Bug 496 (https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/bugs/496/) needs to be fixed to make this of any value.

Comment: Actually, a better shortcut would be `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /c cd "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Extensions\<extension.folder>\" & "%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe"  a ".\<extension.folder>.xpi" -r chrome defaults chrome.manifest install.rdf`. This uses two more environment variables and uses a flag that doesn't leave a cmd.exe window open.

Comment: So, actually, that 7-Zip bug doesn't apply to Mozilla Thunderbird 38.5.1, which means that this shortcut can be used to pack Thunderbird extensions for, at least, the current version of Thunderbird!

Answer (score 3):

Two methods, using the GUI 7zFM.exe, or a command line or batch file.

1.0) **GUI method**.  Assuming 7-Zip is installed with shell integration so you see 7-Zip show up in the context-menu (right-click of selected files) of Windows Explorer.

1.a) Go into the folder of your add-on.

1.b) Select all the files and folders you want to include in the .xpi.  Assuming you don't have any files you want to ignore down in any sub-folders.  If you do, you might want to use the command line option.

1.c) Right-click on the list of selected files, find the `7z` icon, choose the `Add to archive...` option.

1.d) A dialog pops up.  Edit the location and name of the zip file, change to .zip to .xpi, etc.

1.e) Note if you create the .xpi in the same folder, don't re-archive it in the future, as your add-on will fail horribly.  You never want an .xpi ending up inside your .xpi by accident.  I usually just create it in the parent folder, by adding `..\` to the beginning of the file name, e.g.  `..\addon-1.2.3-fx.xpi`

1.f) 7-Zip has a lot of powerful compression options, not all of which Firefox can handle.  Choose settings which Firefox is able to process.  Refer to image.

[image: 7-Zip Settings for XPI Creation]

2.0) **Command Line method**.  Assuming you're in Windows, and know how to open a command prompt, change drives and directories (a.k.a. folders).

2.a) `CD` to your add-on directory.

2.b) Use the most basic 7-Zip command line.

`"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip addon-1.2.3-fx.xpi *`

2.c) You can get a smaller file by finding the exact command line options which correspond to the above GUI, namely:

`"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip -mx=9 -mm=Deflate -mfb=258 -mmt=8 "addon-1.2.3-fx.xpi" *`

Note that there is no Dictionary size = 32kb option when using Deflate Compression method.  Otherwise, the options are in order and correspond to the GUI.

```
|-----------------------|---------|--------------|
| Option / Parameter    | GUI     | Command line |
|-----------------------|---------|--------------|
| Archive format        | zip     | -tzip        |
| Compression level     | Ultra   | -mx=9        |
| Compression method    | Deflate | -mm=Deflate  |
| Dictionary size       | 32 KB   | (none)       |
| Word size             | 258     | -mfb=258     |
| Number of CPU threads | 8       | -mmt=8       |
|-----------------------|---------|--------------|
| Additional Parameters |         |              |
|-----------------------|---------|--------------|
| Recurse into Folders  | (none)  | -r           |
| Multiple passes       | (none)  | -mpass=15    |
| Preserve Timestamps   | (none)  | -mtc=on      |
| Ignore files in list  |         | -x@{ignore}  |
|-----------------------|---------|--------------|
```

Notes:

i) The multi-thread option (-mmt=8) is specific to my system which has 8 cores.  You will need to lower this to 6 or 4 or 2 or 1 (i.e. remove option) if you have fewer cores, etc, or increase if you have more.  Won't make much difference either way for a small extension.

ii) The option to recurse into folder may or may not be the default, so specifying this option should ensure proper recursion.

iii) The option to `preserve windows timestamps` (creation, access, modification) should default to `on` anyways, so may not be needed.

iv) The `ignore files in list` option is any file which has a list of files and wildcards of files you wish to exclude.

2.d) **Advanced topic #1**: ignore file list (examples)

```
|----------------|------------------------------------|
| What to Ignore | Why to Ignore                      |
|----------------|------------------------------------|
| TODO.txt       | Informal reminders of code to fix. |
| *.xpi          | In case you forget warning above!  |
| .ignore        | Ignore the ignore file list.       |
| ignore.txt     | Same thing, if you used this name. |
|----------------|------------------------------------|
```

`"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip -mx9 -mm=Deflate -mfb=258 -mmt=8 -mpass=15 -mtc=on "addon-1.2.3-fx.xpi" * -x@ignore.txt`

2.e) **Advanced topic #2**: Batch file (Windows CMD.EXE), assuming fairly recent windows, i.e. from the 21st century.  This can be as simple and rigid, or complex and flexible as you care to make it.  A general balance is to assume you will be in the `Command Prompt`, in the top level directory of the add-on you are working on, and that you have intelligently named that directory to have the same basename of the .xpi file e.g. `D:\dev\addon-1.2.3-fx` directory for the `addon-1.2.3-fx.xpi` add-on xpi.  This batch file makes this assumption, and dynamically figures out the correct basename to use for the .xpi.

```
@ECHO OFF
REM - xpi.bat - batch file to create Mozilla add-on xpi using 7-Zip

REM - This finds the folder name, and discards the rest of the full path, saves in an environment variable.
FOR %%* IN (.) DO SET XPI=%%~nx*

REM - Uncomment the DEL line, or delete .xpi file manually, if it gets corrupted or includes some other junk by accident.
REM DEL "%XPI%.xpi"

REM - Command line which does everything the GUI does, but also lets you run several passes for the smallest .xpi possible.
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip -r -mx=9 -mm=Deflate -mfb=258 -mmt=8 -mpass=15 -mtc=on "%XPI%.xpi" * -x@ignore.txt
REM - Cleanup the environment variable.
SET XPI=
```

Comment: Thanks.  Just updated with a typo to correct `-mx9`, which should have had an `=` as in `-mx=9`.  Added notes about the multi-thread `-mmt=8` option as well as the recursion `-r` option.  This is how I have successfully packaged add-ons for testing and development and publishing, from XUL, Bootstrap/Restartless/cfm, through SDK/jpm and even with WebExtensions/web-ext.  Sometimes those tools do odd things to the meta files, and you need to modify and repackage by hand.

Answer (score 2):

When pack extension using 7z, compress into .zip and then rename to .xpi, don't compress it.

Answer (score 1):

Do as per the following while using 7z
Select only the inner contents and not the outer folder.
Enter the filename as **filename.xpi** and choose archive format as **zip** in the prompt that appears while zipping.
You will find a valid xpi file created.
Use the created xpi for installing your extension on firefox.
It works!

Answer (score 1):

Just zip all the files and folders inside my_extension folder and change the resulting zipped file's extension to my_extension.xpi

```
/my_extension
  |- defaults/
  |- locale/
  |- resources/
  |- install.rdf
  |- ... (other files and folders)
```

Installation of xpi file created from zipped file of my_extension folder will result error as
"This add-on could not be installed because it appears to be corrupt." error

Answer (score 1):

I try myself to build a zip in several ways because I was convinced I do something wrong 'cause all i got was "package corrupted" stuff .
well.. **not anymore** and I do not even need to load it from Load temporary add-on (now i drag and drop the xpi file from the desktop over Waterfox  and I install it as legit xpi file!
How I do that?
'Cause I try myself the github stuff I load it first in Load temporary add-on (url:about:debugging#addons) the xpi file using the method used by user314159 with the .bat file method that use 7zip.

after you load that you should read somewhere something similar to:

**Extension ID
86257e65ca311ee368ffcee50598ce25733a049b@temporary-addon**

then all you should do is add inside manifest.json modifying the "applications" :

```json
"applications": {
    "gecko": {
      "strict_min_version": "54.0a1",
      "id": "86257e65ca311ee368ffcee50598ce25733a049b@temporary-addon"
    }
  },
```

after this push **Remove** to uninstall the temporary addon then you should build the xpi again like you did before
now is a normal xpi file SIGNED what you can install normal ! (here is works without modifying anything else)

I use Waterfox x64 i's seems to be problems to Firefox

the answer is you should upload your extension on the hub then to use mozilla signing api
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/Distribution

Answer (score 0):

1. Create file **`config.js`**
2. Insert code into `config.js`

```js
try {
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm", {})
.eval("SIGNED_TYPES.clear()");
}
catch(ex) {}
```

3. Move `config.js` to application work folder, eg: `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\`
4. Create `config-prefs.js` and write code into:

```js
pref("general.config.obscure_value", 0);
pref("general.config.filename", "config.js");
```

5. Place `config-pres.js` to `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\defaults\pref\`
6. Restart Firefox
7. Look result

[image]