# How do I make an xpi file and publish my FireFox Extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I have made a simple FireFox  extension and would like to upload it to AMO.

With Chrome this is **DEAD EASY**....zip the directory, upload to the developer dashboard, done.

For FireFox, I apparently have to make my extension into an `xpi` file? How the heck do I do this with FireFox?

I made an account at https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/addon/submit/2

And have read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Distribution but I still can't figure out how to make the xpi file I need to upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPI is simply a ZIP file. Use any ZIP application, make a ZIP of your addon and then change its extension to XPI.

Comment: Yep, I just finally saw that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19240653/how-to-create-xpi-file-with-7zip) . I hate FireFox, it is utterly ridiculous that they do not explain this in their Docs and even more ridiculous that they dont just except the .zip file then

Answer (score -1):

I use a windows batch file (.bat) to build the extension.  It looks like this:

```
set dest=(your extension name)
set ZIP="C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe"
del %dest%.*
%ZIP% a -tzip -mx=9 %dest%.xpi chrome\*
%ZIP% a -tzip -mx=9 %dest%.xpi modules\*
%ZIP% a -tzip -mx=9 %dest%.xpi install.rdf
%ZIP% a -tzip -mx=9 %dest%.xpi chrome.manifest
%ZIP% a -tzip -mx=9 %dest%.xpi defaults\preferences\*
copy %dest%.xpi %dest%.zip"
```